# Unable to pass tkinter callback values to functions

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def browse_button():

    ## Store the path as a global variable
    global folder_path
    filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
    folder_path.set(filename)
    print(filename)
    return folder_path

def outputfile():

    global out_path
    filepath = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes = (("CSV","*.csv"),("all files","*.*")))
    out_path.set(filepath)
    print (filepath)
    return out_path

## Instantiating root widget
root = Tk()

# StringVar and IntVar are a type of control variable. 
#These store values needed later

folder_path= StringVar()
out_path = StringVar()
h20_yr = IntVar()  

wy_lbl= Label(root, text = "Water Year: ")
wy_lbl.grid( row = 0, column = 1)

wy_entry = Entry(root)
wy_entry.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

lbl1 = Label(root, textvariable = folder_path)
lbl1.grid(row = 1, column=1)

browse = Button(text="Input Folder", command=browse_button)
browse.grid(row=1, column=2)

lbl2 = Label(root, textvariable= out_path)
lbl2.grid(row =2, column = 1)

save_as = Button(text = 'Save Output', command = outputfile)
save_as.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

print( folder_path.get(), out_path.get(), h20_yr.get())
```

Novice python user here.

The labels populate and file paths to the chosen folder and output file are printed no problemo through the function call as the button command. Why are these then not stored globally? I need to pass these values to existing code that runs the program.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is utterly pointless to return anything from a Button's `command` - Tkinter is calling that function on your behalf, and is ignoring any return value.  The reason you're not getting anything from that final `print` is that it happens immediately after constructing your GUI: the user has had no chance to actually do anything yet.

Comment: if you add `root.mainloop()` before the last `print()` the print will be executed after the GUI closes. Now the GUI is **never** run.